# Internal Semidirect with Factors Isomorphic to "Outside" Groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, semidirect-product, automorphism-group

Here is a conjecture of mine:

> If $G$ is the internal semidirect product of $N \unlhd G$ and $Q \le G$, and $\phi_1 : N' \to N$ and $\phi_2 : Q' \to Q$ are isomorphisms, then there is some $\theta : Q' \to \text{Aut } N'$ such that $G \cong N' \rtimes_\theta Q'$

My thought was to take $\theta (x) = i_x$ with $i_x(y) = \phi_1( \phi_2(x) \phi_1(y) \phi_2(x)^{-1})$; and then show that $\phi : G \to N' \rtimes_\theta Q'$ given by $\phi(nq) = (\phi_1^{-1}(n),\phi_2^{-1}(q))$ . Assuming that $\theta$ is a homomorphism, I was able to show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism. However, when I went back to verify that $\theta$ is in fact a homomorphism, I ran into seemingly insuperable difficulties. Is $\theta$ as I have defined it a homomorphism? Is it the "right" homomorphism?

Comment: Do you mean $i_x(y) = \phi_1^{-1}( \phi_2(x) \phi_1(y) \phi_2(x)^{-1})$?

Comment: @ArnaudD. Dang it! That was my problem. Without that inverse I wasn't getting the right cancellation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To build on what @ArnaudD. says in a comment . . .*

Using $$i_x(y) = \phi_1^{\color{red}{-1}}( \phi_2(x) \phi_1(y) \phi_2(x)^{-1})$$ instead facilitates the cancellations you were missing.